# Rapidshare download manager accessible over network

Tags: remote-access, download-manager

Basically I am looking for a download manager, which I can run on my server to download rapidshare files, while also being able to access it over the network via a standalone client application or web interface on another machine.

I use [azsmrc](http://azsmrc.sourceforge.net/) for azureus, so something similar to this would be great.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDownloader has a web interface.

Answer (score 0):

If your server runs PHP, you should be OK with [**Rapid Leech**](http://www.rapidleech.com/).

> Rapid Leech is a free server transfer
>   script for use on various popular
>   upload/download sites such as
>   megaupload.com, Rapidshare.com and
>   more than 45 others. The famous
>   Rapidleech script transfers files from
>   Rapidshare, Megaupload,
>   Depositfiles.com, Easy-share.com, etc,
>   via your fast servers connection speed
>   and dumps the file on your server. You
>   may then download these files from
>   your server anytime later.